# JQVMap json data from php

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I've taken the data I need on the map, converted into JSON, and I'm trying to figure out how to put it in the values: part of the jquery. I think I have to put var data somewhere but I'm not sure how to put that into the .js script.

php script:

```
    $csel = $odb->query("SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM bots GROUP BY country ORDER BY cnt ");
$rows = array();
$rows2 = array();
 while ($c = $csel->fetch())
                                    {
                    $top2 = geoip_country_name_by_id($gi, $c[0]);
                    $top = number_format($c[1]);

                    $rows[] = $top2;
                    $rows2[] = $top;


  }
$c = array_combine($rows, $rows2);

echo json_encode($c);
```

JQVMap part:

```
<script>

  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
      map: 'world_en',
      backgroundColor: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff',
      hoverOpacity: 0.7,
      selectedColor: '#666666',
      enableZoom: true,
      showTooltip: true,
      scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
      values: <?php echo json_encode($c)?>,
      normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'

    });
  });
</script>
```

How would I put the data into the map? Right now its showing nothing.